# Problem reading a TStream in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, types, byte, delphi-xe, tstream

In the previous versions of Delphi, the following code:

```
   var InBuf: array[1..45] of Byte;

   Count := InStream.Read(InBuf, SizeOf(InBuf));
```

filled the variable InBuf with the correct values ( every byte had a value ). Now in Delphi XE, every second byte of the array is 0, I suppose because the Byte data type is twice as big, because of its Unicode nature in Delphi XE. But, my streams are already generated and need to pass through this procedure, so I need another type (maybe?) that is half size of Byte or another solution if someone faced this problem. Thanks

Comment: Byte is still a Byte in XE. It seems the stream contains a unicode string now, however. Check the code that populates the stream.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What has happened here, with >99% probability is that you have written the stream from a string variable.  Unicode strings with UTF-16 encoding have two bytes per character whereas older versions of Delphi using ANSI encodings with one byte per character.

English text, when encoded with UTF-16 have the pattern you observe of every second  byte being zero.

In order to solve this you will need to investigate the section of code that writes to the stream.